# Equal distribution of marks in student group

Tags: mysql

I have the database of students of a particular school.

```
student_name |math | science| english| social
---------------------------------------------
Aakas        | 80  |  70    |   90   |   55
Aphi         | 30  |  80    |   67   |   79
Geeta        | 60  |  89    |   95   |   87
pradip       | 70  |  78    |   67   |   65
Nikita       | 45  |  78    |   90   |   48
Shanti       | 69  |  90    |   67   |   84
```

the students numbers n is say 1000.

The thing I need to do is divide the student into 'm' groups(for example m is 250). Such that each subject of a group should have nearly average marks. For the above the average marks of math is 59(for given six students) for considering math only. If we divide six students into two groups each containing 3 students. Group 1 = `{Aakas, Abhi, Geeta}` group 2 = `{Pradip, Nikita, Shanti}`

Group 1 has average `56.67` in math which is near to `59` group 2 has average `61.33` in math which is near to `59`

Which is the case considering math only. We have to consider for all subjects such that each group have an average marks near to the average of individual subject of whole students. How to solve it?

Comment: can you show the format of output you need?

Comment: That looks more like a spreadsheet than any kind of relational database object.

Comment: the output should be like this:
group1 = { Aakas, Abhi, Geeta}
group2 = {Pradip, Nikita, Shanti} and so on 

The thing is i need to divide the whole group of student where each group have few member(in this case 3) keeping in mind that whole group should have nearly equal marks in all subject

Comment: Steps:
1.First make initial groups for my case I make groups 
  group1 = {Aakas, Aphi, Geeta}
  group2 = {pradip, Nikita, Shanti} and so on.
  
Then I calculate the mean of each subjects.
mean_math, mean_science, mean_english, mean_social.

calculate distance from group1 to mean marks and similary from group2 
to mean marks using Euclidean distance.

Now I swap each tuple from group1 and group2 for example if I swap Aakas and pradip so that eulidean distance from total mean and new group if minimizes then take new group otherwise take group before swapping.

Comment: but the above methods don't work well.

Answer (score 1):

A database TABLE is not a SPREADSHEET.

Whatever problem it is that you think you're trying to solve, the first step will be to normalize your schema to something a lot more like the following:

```
+--------------+---------+-------+
| student_name | subject | score |
+--------------+---------+-------+
| Aakas        | math    |    80 |
| Aphi         | math    |    30 |
| Geeta        | math    |    60 |
| pradip       | math    |    70 |
| Nikita       | math    |    45 |
| Shanti       | math    |    69 |
| Aakas        | science |    70 |
| Aphi         | science |    80 |
| Geeta        | science |    89 |
| pradip       | science |    78 |
| Nikita       | science |    78 |
| Shanti       | science |    90 |
| Aakas        | english |    90 |
| Aphi         | english |    67 |
| Geeta        | english |    95 |
| pradip       | english |    67 |
| Nikita       | english |    90 |
| Shanti       | english |    67 |
| Aakas        | social  |    55 |
| Aphi         | social  |    79 |
| Geeta        | social  |    87 |
| pradip       | social  |    65 |
| Nikita       | social  |    48 |
| Shanti       | social  |    84 |
+--------------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy clustering problem, you can use K-Means